# Keeping a view from the begin of the app to the end

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to make a view that can be call in anywhere, anytime, it start from the begin of the app and keep it till the end.

It seems like a map in a game that you can access everytime you want and it update where you are

Comment: Define that view in AppDelegate, and access from other viewControllers when you want..

Comment: If i have some field that user inputs, they're keeped or gone?

Comment: Yes, the textfield text you entered will be there till the end.

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Define your variable in **AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyGameMapViewController *myGameMapViewController;
```

2) initialise the variable in **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method of AppDelegate.m

```
self.myGameMapViewController =  [[MyGameMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyGameMapViewController" bundle:nil];
```

3) Present your myGameMapViewController from other viewControllers,

```
AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[self presentViewController:appDel.myGameMapiewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

4) add the following method to your **myGameViewController**'s button press,

```
-(IBAction) temporaryCloseButtonPressed:(id)sender;{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

*make sure you have imported AppDelegate.h in your view controller.*

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Comment: Yes, the textfield text you entered will be there till the end.